# Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined - Angular 4.1 - System JS - NG BootStrap

Tags: angular, systemjs, ng-bootstrap

i'm just trying to include ng-bootstrap in my simple Angular 4 application.

I get error

> "Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined" when application
>   loading.

I'm using SystemJS with this configuration:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/es6-shim"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
        },
        map: {
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5.4.0',
        },
        packages: {
            '': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

and my tsconfig.json is like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./Scripts"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This is my app.module.ts code

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BidService } from './app.services.bid'; 

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        BidService
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have created a plunker with transpiled javascript:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IWSR6PmbgQ6i7A6qrdlu

Many Thanks

Comment: You should create the plunkr with typescript code, not transpilled javascript as it can't really help us to find the error. The error seems to be a bad import in your app module but checking it in the transpilled javascript is harder.

Comment: Can you share the ts code of your appmodule?

Comment: I have added my app.module.ts code.

Comment: I think this is an issue with your version of system.js - with a different version your [plunkr works](http://plnkr.co/edit/sTuvYNZiCoe46P4O68PF?p=preview)

Comment: Many thanks Und3rTow, with version 0.19.31 it works.
How can you find that problem is SystemJs version?